# pgPromise how to kill all db connections on Jest unit test completion

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

In my Jest unit test file that uses pgPromise library I am getting this error:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

I guess this should be because of the code below that I have in my app.ts

```
import {db} from './shared/db';
...
let sco: any;
db.connect().then(function (obj: any) {
  sco = obj;
  obj.client.query('LISTEN "table_update"');
  obj.client.on('notification', function (data: any) {
      var result = JSON.parse(data.payload);
  log.info(result);
  globalEmitter.emit(
    eventTypes.Entity_Data_Changed, 
    result
}
catch(error) {
  log.error({ error }, 'Error happened');
})
.finally(() => {
// release the connection, if it was successful:
 if (sco) {
    sco.done();
 }
```

});;

I use the same import in my unit test file.

db is coming from

```
const db = pgp(options);
```

In my unit test file I have this code at the end

```
afterAll(async done => {
setImmediate(done); // jest address open handle with --detectOpenHandles
db.$pool.end();
pgp.end();});
```

I tried pgp.end() to kill all connections as I suspect the db expression in app.ts file does not belong to a connection pool as I read somewhere about it before. But still no luck. any help would be appreciated here.

Comment: When you use manual [connect](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#connect), you need to call `done` in the end. You do not show doing that. Also, there is no point calling `.$pool.end()`, if you are calling `pgp.end()` right after, which ends all pools in the process.

Comment: are you testing the database itself? if not, consider mocking the database.

Comment: @DanielA.White, yes that is an iteration test actually

Comment: @vitaly-t I updated my code. Actually that db.connect purpose is to create a connection that keeps open during the application lifecycle. Not sure how I can use done in that situation.  I added that pgp.end() after I met this issue as you said I dont need the db.pool. However pgp.end is not working. I am using const pgp = require('pg-promise')({}); at the beginning of the test file. is that correct?

Comment: `Not sure how I can use done in that situation` - there is nothing special here. When your test finishes, call `done` on the allocated connection. Not calling it results in connection hanging outside of the pool, because you are using `connect`.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t, so I updated my code as reflected above and it worked. I guess that was what you meant. please advise if otherwise. thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Hi @vitaly-t, The finally block I added to the db.connect works in unit test scenario but when I run the application it quite immediately terminates the connection which is unwanted. can you please advise what I did wrong here?

Comment: Just follow [the basic example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#streaming), plus [the advanced example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Robust-Listeners). When you close the connection, it stops listening, obviously.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t. I read them. so what I did at the end was like from the test case I am sending a notification with a specific msg  to the event listener in that db.connect and there it just cheks msg and terminate the connection if matched. not sure if this is the best approach. but it is working. Previously I had tried exposing the connection obj and use its done method in the unit test but it did not work.